# create and rename multiple copies of files

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file `input.txt` that looks as follows.

```
abas_1.txt
abas_2.txt
abas_3.txt
1fgh.txt
3ghl_1.txt
3ghl_2.txt
```

I have a folder `ff`. The filenames of this folder are `abas.txt`, `1fgh.txt`, `3ghl.txt`. Based on the input file, I would like to create and rename the multiple copies in ff folder.

For example in the input file, `abas` has three copies. In the `ff` folder, I need to create the three copies of `abas.txt` and rename it  as `abas_1.txt`, `abas_2.txt`, `abas_3.txt`. No need to copy and rename `1fgh.txt` in ff folder.

Your valuable suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this (to be run from within your folder `ff`):

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r fn; do
    [[ $fn =~ ^(.+)_[[:digit:]]+\.([^\.]+)$ ]] || continue
    fn_orig=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    echo cp -nv -- "$fn_orig" "$fn"
done < input.txt
```

Remove the `echo` if you're happy with it.

If you don't want to run from within the folder `ff`, just replace the line

```
echo cp -nv -- "$fn_orig" "$fn"
```

with

```
echo cp -nv -- "ff/$fn_orig" "ff/$fn"
```

The `-n` option to `cp` so as to not overwrite existing files, and the `-v` option to be verbose. The `--` tells `cp` that there are no more options beyond this point, so that it will not be confused if one of the files starts with a hyphen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code doesn't work.It just prints the name of the files. I would like to create  and rename the files in ff folder.

Comment: @user3556280 I know it only prints the command to be executed... you must remove the `echo` so that the command is really executed (it's specified in the answer).

Comment: I am really sorry. I didn't see that. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

using `for` and `grep` :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(ls)
do
  x=$(echo $i | sed 's/^\(.*\)\..*/\1/')"_"
  for j in $(grep $x in)
  do
    cp -n $i $j
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
#!/bin/bash
while read newFileName;do
    #split the string by _ delimiter
    arr=(${newFileName//_/ })
    extension="${newFileName##*.}"
    fileToCopy="${arr[0]}.$extension"
    #check for empty : '1fgh.txt' case
    if [ -n "${arr[1]}" ]; then
        #check if file exists
        if [ -f $fileToCopy ];then
           echo "copying $fileToCopy -> $newFileName"
           cp "$fileToCopy" "$newFileName"
        #else
        #   echo "File $fileToCopy does not exist, so it can't be copied"
        fi
    fi  
done
```

You can call your script like this:

```
cat input.txt | ./script.sh
```

Comment: This method assumes there's only one underscore in the filenames and no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you could change the format of `input.txt`, I suggest you adjust it in order to make your task easier. If not, here is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
SRC_DIR=/path/to/ff
INPUT=/path/to/input.txt
BACKUP_DIR=/path/to/backup
for cand in `ls $SRC_DIR`; do
    grep "^${cand%.*}_" $INPUT | while read new
    do
        cp -fv $SRC_DIR/$cand $BACKUP_DIR/$new
    done
done
```

Comment: Why not `ls`? We have to tell bash what files we are to deal with.